# Activate Excel Add-Ins as part of Deployment?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, deployment

I am using the office customization tool to create an unattended installation file for Microsoft Office 2010 pro plus. I have everything setup as I like, except that I need the excel add-ins activated (Analysis ToolPak, Analysis ToolPak - VBA, Euro Currency Tools, Solver.)

There is a section of the office tool that lets me customize the features, and I have configured the entire excel branch to be "Run from my computer," but the add-ins are still grayed out.

Does anybody know how to activate these excel add-ins via command line or registry entries? Am I missing something with the office customization tool?

Comment: Looks like you can use GPO and registry. This question was answered over here: https://superuser.com/questions/1165927/excel-activate-addin-through-a-group-policy-object