# excel - activate addin through a Group Policy object

Tags: microsoft-excel, group-policy, microsoft-excel-2016

I have an addin that I'm installing on the roaming profile of users.

Yet I have to activate it manually for every users.

[image]

I thought about activating it automatically with GPO.

I read [that](https://www.add-in-express.com/docs/net-deploying-addins.php) but it seems to be big for what it is.

Is there a way to activate it automatically with a GPO, in a simpler way?

Thanks

Comment: Have you see the accepted answer here: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28654905/Enable-an-Excel-add-in-that-has-already-been-installed-via-Group-Policy-GPO.html... `There are two reg keys that you'll need

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins

I would go to a machine that has it enabled and export the keys with the addin you want and run it in conjunction with GPO

I've provided the link as a guide to how to force enabling of addins

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2733070`

Comment: Here's a post regarding the potentially needed GPP settings... https://blog.thesysadmins.co.uk/group-policy-preferences-1-deploying-registry-settings.html to push the registry keys values to the needed machines via GPO... If you find this helpful and would like me to add as an answer, just hit me back and let me know... Good luck!!

Comment: Hi @ITSolutions, how do I save the reg keys and reimplement it on a different laptop? From far, your solutions seems to be the easiest but there are a few technicalities where I need some light... Thanks

Comment: You essentially can just navigate to each of the regedit locations for both of those paths listed (on the machine where it works/is activated), and then select the actual reg folder with the name that correlates to the add-in, right-click on it and select export, and then save that to the desktop for example. Then the reg files that were exported can be copied over to the new machine that need to have this activated and then just double-click import those into the registry of the new machine. Now try, reboot and then try again, etc. [Screen Shot Example](https://i.imgur.com/VbSFfwj.png)

Comment: If you're asking how to implement this with GPP, I'd look here at [this post](https://blog.thesysadmins.co.uk/group-policy-preferences-1-deploying-registry-settings.html) and navigate down to **Example 2** and implement that there with settings that match for the registry keys that export correlated to the add-in and use the UPDATE method as mentioned. I'll be glad to add as an answer with more detail if you find that this solves you're problem but this is the detail in brief and I know it's not super hard to complete (you're already familiar with GP).

Comment: Hi @ITSolutions I looked in regedit at the folder `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins` and also for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins`. I did not find anything in it... Any help are more than welcomed as it does not make sense where this ****ing addins is installing itself

Comment: @ITSolutions I tried by regedit. I could not find the regkeys as mentioned in your example. I tried to create them both in current user and local machine. Then I deactivated the addin, closed excel and hoping that excel would reactivate it. But no luck, the addin is still deactivated

Comment: Start of my solution http://bettersolutions.com/excel/add-ins/registry-keys.htm

Comment: and here too https://www.windows-commandline.com/add-registry-key-command-line/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to make my addin, enabled through a GPIO

You copy the addin on the user's machine and enabled it with the following command line in a command prompt

```
reg  add  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options  /v  OPEN /t  REG_SZ  /d  "DW_connector.xlam"
```

Please note that you will need to put to change the version of office, based on your version of excel

> - Excel 2016 - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options
> - Excel 2013 - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Excel\Options
> - Excel 2010 - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Excel\Options
> - Excel 2007 - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Excel\Options

Comment: That's fine if this is the first add-in installed on each account. But if one is already installed, then the registry entry OPEN is already taken, and you must use OPEN1. Then OPEN2, OPEN3, etc.

Answer (score 1):

first solution that need to test:

i remember that in [excel 2007 we can make mst file](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179057(v=office.12).aspx) and install with msi in your network by active directory GPO

In this [walkthrough](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/odsupport/2009/06/10/office-2007-customized-install-walkthrough/) we will create a custom Office 2007 source. We will customize our Office 2007 installation via the config.xml and the Office Customization wizard.

1. by [regedit](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28654905/Enable-an-Excel-add-in-that-has-already-been-installed-via-Group-Policy-GPO.html)

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins

[Configure a Registry Item with GPO](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753092(v=ws.11).aspx)

2. [technet article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3125f5bc-f887-48a7-8111-ef9770034147/enabling-excel-addins-via-group-policy?forum=officesetupdeployprevious)

Another solution If you can programming or have a programmer in your team, Create New project with Visual Studio and generate msi file that do those actions you need.

then [use Group Policy to remotely install software](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/816102) with OU's

you can do more actions with DotNet by C# or VB.net or other syntaxes.

actions like copy activate file to specific directory or etc. here is examples

1. [make changes in regedit.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24895430/308578)
2. [change content of text file in your](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13509665/308578) installation directory
3. copy dll to desired destination
4. [put your app in startup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/674654/308578)
5. install [background service in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11027245/308578)
6. [show balloon tooltip for users](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8716963/308578) like notifications in Android
7. Run PowerShell commands for complete registration and activation
8. copy every licence from Map Network drive to every target PC
9. connect to your SharePoint Server or SQL Database and read information from excel shared filed

gpo install it in your joined computers and execute it (Members in your Active Directory)

Comment: Hi @saber-tabatabaee-yazdi what do you mean by `excel 2007 we can make mst file`? Where you meaning `MSI` install file instead?

Comment: i remember Microsoft office had tools for that that we make mst after msi browse

Comment: hi @saber-tabatabaee-yazdi if you have any official doc, I'm all ears

Comment: @AndyK updated the  answer .... line 4 ... click on link walkthrough .. if problem comment for me ... This question has an open bounty worth +50 reputation from Andy K ending in 4 days.

Comment: I tried by regedit. I could not find the regkeys as mentioned in your example. I tried to create them both in current user and local machine. Then I deactivated the addin, closed excel and hoping that excel would reactivate it. But no luck, the addin is still deactivated

Comment: we cant suggest a crack or teach how to patchs softwares in superuser if you have licensed PC copy from there ...find it in windows registery ... your question about How to do that by GPO.. that possible

Comment: hi @saber-tabatabaee-yazdi, I found my solution